# A way to turn KCl into KOH is needed

Tags: acid-base

I figured out that KCl + NaOH may result in KOH but I think this reaction can not happen in an aqueous medium. So there I have a couple of questions.

1. Is there a way to make the reaction I stated above to happen?
2. Is there a way to turn KCl into KOH?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I think the reaction does not works very well, because you get an equilibrium of KOH and NaOH.
2. If you have KCl in an aqueous solution you can use AgOH to get KOH. AgCl precipitate and the solution contains only KOH. If you like to get KOH it is better to buy them.

Answer (score 6):

On an industrial scale, the preferred method for the production of potassium hydroxide from potassium chloride is electrolysis (diaphragm, mercury, or membrane process).

$$\begin{align}
\ce{2Cl- &-> Cl2 + 2e-}\\
\ce{2H2O + 2e- &-> H2 + 2OH-}\\
\hline
\ce{2Cl- + 2H2O &-> Cl2 + H2 + 2OH-}
\end{align}$$

or

$$\ce{2KCl + 2H2O -> 2KOH + Cl2 + H2}$$